# Scala convert object to JSON response

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http, spray-json

How can I convert the following case class object to JSON response, the case class contains multiple nested object value.

I got exception when I use `jsonFormat5(responseData)`

```
val simpleBanner1 = Banner(112, "http://dummyimage.com/300x250", 300, 250)
val responseData = BidResponse(uuid, "XN2zZQABxJsKK0jU4QnIzw", campaignData.bid, Option("4548"), Option(simpleBanner1))
```

#### Exception

```
Error:(63, 47) could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type bidder.RestService.JF[Option[bidder.Banner]]
implicit val bidResponseFormat = jsonFormat5(BidResponse)

Error:(63, 47) not enough arguments for method jsonFormat5: (implicit evidence$25: bidder.RestService.JF[String], implicit evidence$26: bidder.RestService.JF[String], implicit evidence$27: bidder.RestService.JF[Double], implicit evidence$28: bidder.RestService.JF[Option[String]], implicit evidence$29: bidder.RestService.JF[Option[bidder.Banner]], implicit evidence$30: scala.reflect.ClassTag[bidder.BidResponse])spray.json.RootJsonFormat[bidder.BidResponse].
Unspecified value parameters evidence$29, evidence$30.
implicit val bidResponseFormat = jsonFormat5(BidResponse)

Error:(76, 28) Cannot find JsonWriter or JsonFormat type class for bidder.BidResponse
          responseData.toJson
Error:(76, 28) not enough arguments for method toJson: (implicit writer: spray.json.JsonWriter[bidder.BidResponse])spray.json.JsValue.
Unspecified value parameter writer.
          responseData.toJson
```

Answer (score 1):

`jsonFormat5` should be used with the case class, as it defines how to the object should be encoded. Your code should look like this:

```
import spray.json._
import DefaultJsonProtocol._

// define format implicitly for BidResponse and Banner case classes
implicit val bannerFormat = jsonFormat4(Banner)
implicit val bidResponseFormat = jsonFormat5(BidResponse)

// serialize BidResponse object
val bidResponseJson = responseData.toJson
```

Here is an extended example:

```
import spray.json._
import DefaultJsonProtocol._

// example case classes
case class Banner(num: Int, url: String, num2: Int, num3: Int)
case class BidResponse(uuid: String, code: String, num: Int, opt: Option[String], banner: Option[Banner])

implicit val bformat = jsonFormat4(Banner)
implicit val format = jsonFormat5(BidResponse)

val simpleBanner1 = Banner(112, "http://dummyimage.com/300x250", 300, 250)
val responseData = BidResponse("abcdef", "XN2zZQABxJsKK0jU4QnIzw", 1234, Option("4548"), Option(simpleBanner1))

println( responseData.toJson )
```

As mentioned in the comments, the Banner format must be defined implicitly because the BidResponse object depends on it. ref: `bformat` variable.

Comment: Hi @terminally-chill, I already tried it before, got exception `Error:(63, 47) could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type bidder.RestService.JF[Option[bidder.Banner]]
  implicit val bidResponseFormat = jsonFormat5(BidResponse)`

Comment: `Error:(63, 47) not enough arguments for method jsonFormat5: (implicit evidence$25: bidder.RestService.JF[String], implicit evidence$26: bidder.RestService.JF[String], implicit evidence$27: bidder.RestService.JF[Double], implicit evidence$28: bidder.RestService.JF[Option[String]], implicit evidence$29: bidder.RestService.JF[Option[bidder.Banner]], implicit evidence$30: scala.reflect.ClassTag[bidder.BidResponse])spray.json.RootJsonFormat[bidder.BidResponse].
Unspecified value parameters evidence$29, evidence$30.
  implicit val bidResponseFormat = jsonFormat5(BidResponse)`

Comment: @AbdulAwal you should add Banner as an implicit val as well. Updated the answer showing both in scope.

Comment: I update it as `implicit val simpleBanner1 = Banner(112, "http://dummyimage.com/300x250", 300, 250)`
but the error remain the same

Comment: @AbdulAwal Can you include the case class definitions? I can re-create this exception when using the wrong `jsonFormat` function. Are there any default values in the case class definition?

Comment: full source code can be found here `https://github.com/devawal/akka-http-bidder/blob/master/src/main/scala/bidder/RestService.scala`
I think it will be better if you just have a look in my code, maybe there is a simple mistake

Comment: @AbdulAwal please add `implicit val bannerFormat = jsonFormat4(Banner)` on line 62 and it will work

Comment: Thank you @terminally-chill, you just save my day :)
Please add this as an answer so that others will see the solution